# Abstract class avoid creating multiple instances of object to pass different inputs

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I'm trying to refactor a class using abstract class and am trying to understand if my approach is correct.

For every object I receive, I've a base validator which does some basic checks and then have a custom validator which performs some extra validations based on type of object. I feel this is a good use of abstract classes.

```
public abstract class Validator {
    BaseValidator baseValidator;
    abstract void customValidation();

    void validateObject() {
        baseValidator.validate(getInputObject());
        customValidation();
    }

    abstract String getInputObject();
}

public TypeAValidator extends Validator {
    @Override
    public void customValidation() {
        //Do something with getInputObject();
    }

    @Override public String getInputObject() {
        return "someInput";
    }
}
```

I don't think having every input as part of a getter seems the right approach. If I went with a non abstract class approach, I would do this :

```
public TypeAValidator {
    BaseValidator baseValidator;

    public void validateObject(String inputObject) {
        baseValidator.validate(inputObject);
        customValidation(inputObject);
    }
}
```

With this approach, all I need to do is call `typeAValidator.validateObject(inputObject)` without creating a new instance of `TypeAValidator` everytime which I will need to do with the abstract class approach. Is there something wrong with the way I've modelled my abstract class.

Comment: I am not sure, if I understood your question correctly, so please correct me, if I'm wrong. You want to implement a Validator for specific kind of data and some checks have to be performed commonly on every type, so you want to delegate these checks to a common base class?

Comment: @JanHeld yes that's right. I want to create only one instance of TypeAValidator as well.

Comment: Okay, and do you have multiple sub-classes you need to check, e.g. ClassA mit subclasses ClassB and ClassC and TypeValidator for ClassB is different from TypeValidator for ClassC but both share the common checks implemented in BaseValidator?

Comment: Generally each TypeValidator needs to check only one type.

Comment: Okay, hopefully last question: Do the classes to be checked share some common base class? So BaseValidator can check everything present in BaseClass and TypedValidatorA checks everything in SubClassA, TypedValidatorB checks things in SubClassB or how are the classes to be checked related?

Comment: At this point there is nothing common to be shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix your own two solutions to make something like this

```
public abstract class Validator {
    BaseValidator baseValidator;

    protected abstract void customValidationOnObject(String inputObject);

    public void validateObject(String inputObject) {
        baseValidator.validate(inputObject);
        customValidationOnObject(inputObject);
    }
}

class TypeAValidator extends Validator{

    @Override
    protected void customValidationOnObject(String inputObject) {
        // custom validate the Object
    }
}
```

And you can call `TypeAValidator.validateObject(inputObject)` on a single TypeAValidator object.